# preg_match php regex guillemet

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have this char :

```
<span class=\"studySummaryOval arial_14 bold neutral\" title=\"NEUTRE\">XXX</span>
<span class=\"studySummaryOval arial_14 bold buy\" title=\"buy\">XXX</span>
<span class=\"studySummaryOval arial_14 bold buy\" title=\"sell\">XXX</span>
```

How to take XXX with php, preg_match ?

My work just with sell but not with other !

I have this code(with php, preg_match) :

```
|<span class=\\\\"studySummaryOval arial_14 bold sell\\\\" title=\\\\"(.*)\\\\">(.*)</span>|
```

i don't know !

Big thank !

Comment: Removed perl tag, since this has no relation to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a sell word in regex change it to:

```
|<span class=\\\\"studySummaryOval arial_14 bold .*\\\\" title=\\\\"(.*)\\\\">(.*)</span>|
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class=\\\"studySummaryOval arial_14 bold .*?\\\" title=\\\"sell\\\">(.*?)<\/span>
```